# Trying to delete all Rows until Cell (A,1) has certain value

Tags: excel, vba

Having issues in VBA

Trying to delete all rows until value in row 1 = "**GRAD*"

I get Runtime Error 438

Code Below

```
Public Sub Delete()

Dim i As Long

i = 1 'Start from row 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Do Until .Range("A" & i).Value = "**GRAD"
        If .Rage("A" & i).Value <> "**GRAD" Then
            .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Else: i = i + 1 'Only increment if the row hasn't been deleted to        prevent skipping rows
        End If
    Loop

End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Some help would be appreciated, new to VBA.

Comment: You might want to include the case that `Range("A" & i).Value = vbNullString`. Otherwise, the above code might run indefinitely (if `**GRAD` is never found) and might even crash your computer. That's why I (personally) try to avoid `Do Loop` altogether and use `For ... Next` only (with a definite ending row, even if it has to be to the last row = 1,048,576).

Comment: Always use `option explicit` and your typos will be easily identified !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L.Dutch already gave you the answer to your question

here's an alternative and faster approach

> to delete all rows until value in *column* 1 = "**GRAD*"

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Delete()
    Dim lastRowToDelete As Long
    Dim f As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet0001") '<-- reference your worksheet
        With Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<-- reference its columns "A" cells from row 1 sown to last not empty one
            Set f = .Find(what:="**GRAD", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, after:=.Range("A" & .Rows.Count)) '<-- look for the first cell whose value is "**GRAD"
            If f Is Nothing Then '<-- if not found then...
                lastRowToDelete = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row '<-- the last row to delete is the last row of the range
            Else '<-- otherwise...
                lastRowToDelete = f.Row - 1 '<-- the last row to delete is the one preceeding the one with the found cell
            End If
        End With
        If lastRowToDelete > 0 Then .Range("A1:A" & lastRowToDelete).EntireRow.Delete 'delete all rows in a single shot
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a lot faster i Have tried to modify your code to delete all rows after a blank row but i think my method is dirty,

Comment: you may want to post a new question with your new issue "how to delete all rows after a blank row", adding both more details and, mostly, _your_ code attempts

Comment: Thank you, for your help i am pretty new to this site.

Answer (score 1):

Typo? I read `If .Rage("A" & i).Value <> "**GRAD" Then` while it should be `If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "**GRAD" Then`

Comment: probably you are new here, instead of "thanks" it is appreciated to recognize the answer by marking it useful or accepted